# Cache Busting in blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

Is there any solution for Cache busting in Blazor? I Converted my asp.net core application in Blazor WebAssembly, where I was using `asp-append-version=true` in razor pages for client cache update.

[Found](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10198) same issue with DLLs

Comment: Use a service worker to cache the files, and update the cache version when you want the client to update. `<plug>BlazorPWA.MSBuild</plug>` is a free and open source package on nuget that does all the setup for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding my answer based on @Mister Comment.

`BlazorPWA.MSBuild` nuget package is to generate PWA required files.

For Update Cache, you have changes your proj file every time when you are going to publish code.

```
<ServiceWorkerCacheVersion>1</ServiceWorkerCacheVersion>
<ServiceWorkerForce>true</ServiceWorkerForce>
```

Check this [like](https://dev.to/bradwellsb/a-simple-way-to-create-a-pwa-with-blazor-webassembly-1fln) if you want to implement this nuget package.

Comment: at this moment the package is deprecated. At least in nuget

Comment: All solutions for this problem seem to rely on this nuget package, but the package is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

I and my coleagues [Nurzhan Aitbayev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1723722/nurzhan-aitbayev), [Yerassyl Shalabayev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6186459/era) developed followed solution:

1. Store version in web.client's wwwroot/appsettings.json

```
"ApplicationSettings": {
    ...
    "Version": "Release-0"
  }
```

2. Store version in web.server appsettings.json

```
"ApplicationSettings": {
    ...
    "Version": "Release-0"
  }
```

3. Web server always returns actual version in header:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Application-Version", Configuration["ApplicationSettings:Version"]);
                await next.Invoke();
            });
```

4. Client check version every response

```
private void CheckAppVersion(HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            if (response == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(response));
            }

            response.Headers.TryGetValues("Application-Version", out var headers);
            if (headers == null || !headers.Any())
            {
                return;
            }

            var appVersion = headers.First();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appVersion))
            {
                var localVersion = _applicationSettings.Version;
                var isActual = string.Compare(localVersion, appVersion, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

                if (isActual != 0)
                {
                    throw new OldVersionException("Версия приложения обновилась");
                }
            }
        }
```

5. If user has exception then reload page:
   C#

```
protected async Task RefreshPageAsync()
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("reloadPage");
        }
```

JS

```
<script>
        function reloadPage() {
            location.reload(true);
        }
    </script>
```